# API Gateway configuration returns 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

I have an `API Gateway` configured and deployed. If I make a GET request to one of its staged endpoints, for example `https://1234567890.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/doc`, I get a `200 OK` response.

If I take a look at the `Custom Domain Names` section and supplant the URL found there into my request, for example `abcdefghijkl-f4cwy0d1u5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` to make `https://abcdefghijkl-f4cwy0d1u5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/doc`, I get `403 Forbidden`.

Am I wrong in thinking that I should be able to make a request to the domain name - and thus use the API's Custom domain name in a CNAME record - or does the 403 indicate that a specific configuration item is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** When getting `403 Forbidden` with API Gateway and using the `Custom domain name` it's important to trim the stage name because API Gateway is routing the custom name to that stage.

Using [the documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/) provided by @leoandreotti I was able to identify the response header:

```
x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException
```

For this, the documentation states:

> Invoking a REST API that has a custom domain name using the default
> execute-api endpoint - The caller uses the default execute-api
> endpoint to invoke a REST API after disabling the default endpoint.

This made me think back to a header I had been recommended to use by a colleague - the `Host` header.

So, I added the header back into the request and got this:

```
x-amzn-ErrorType: MissingAuthenticationTokenException
```

For which the docs state:

> Resource path doesn't exist - A request with no "Authorization" header
> is sent to an API resource path that doesn't exist.

But the path `/dev/doc` absolutely does exist. Then I realised that the `/dev` portion is actually the **stage** name.

So I trimmed the `/dev` portion from the path and got `200 OK` - then I removed the `Host` header and also got `200 OK`!

Thanks @leoandreotti

Answer (score 2):

you can find some response headers that come together with your 403 error here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/

this might help you to find which error you are facing!

Comment: Thank you - I've solved the problem from the resource you provided.